# How do I delete a local branch on Github Desktop?

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

Last week I upgraded my Windows Github to [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

It is certainly a lot faster than that last update they made for Github Windows. It also has a nice little visual timeline of commits and maybe I am being dumb, but **the ability to delete local branches seems to be gone**.

Before it was under “manage branches” (also gone). Any idea?

**Update:**

In [v3.0.5](https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/windows/) they have added the option to delete local branches from the gear menu.
[image]

Comment: Just a hint: The commit visual timeline is really useful when using Git Flow ;)

Comment: True! I was maybe a little harsh on it... it is pretty cool haha

Answer (score 40):

**On Mac OSX:**

for everyone having this problem with the latest version:
Select the branch that you want to delete, go to "Branch" -> "Delete Branch"

[image: Github Desktop (Mac OSX)]

**On Windows:**

[image: Github Desktop (Windows)]

Answer (score 22):

Here's the answer I got from github CS when I contacted them about this:

> Thu 2015-08-13 3:38 PM Hi Daniel,
>   Sorry about that! We'll be adding the option to delete branches back in an upcoming release. For now however, here's how you can delete a branch from the Git Shell:
>   Hit ~ in GitHub Desktop to open up the repository in the Git Shell
>   Run 'git branch -d branch_name'
>   When you create a new branch you should see an option to publish it directly in the comparison graph.
>   Let me know if that doesn't make sense or if you have more questions - thanks and sorry for the inconvenience!
>   Robert

I've noticed there is a delay (about 2 or 3 minutes) between deleting the local branch in the shell and git desktop realizing the change.

**UPDATE**

In 3.0.5 They added Delete the current branch from the gear menu.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your reply. I have been using Git Shell to delete  branches and I have not had any delay on Github Desktop when the branch is deleted, strange.

Nice to see that they have this fix in an upcoming release.

Comment: @ danielml01 looks like the delete current branch has been added only for Windows version?

Comment: @klode, I thought so as well, but you can find it under the "Branch" menu on the Mac client.

Answer (score 15):

In GitHub Desktop, you can delete the current branch here:

[image]

With the following dialog allowing you to delete it from remote as well:

[image]

Comment: "Branch" -> "Delete..." is disabled in version 1.2.2?

Comment: (After seeing this) I just updated to 1.2.2, created a local branch then deleted that local branch with no issue. Could you post this as a new SO issue with images of the issue and we can debug it?

Comment: You don't have to have the particular branch selected. Just right-click it in the pull-down list of branches and hit Delete to show the window you have in your answer.

Answer (score 10):

In desktop, make sure you are in the correct branch, and press "ctr+shift+D".This should delete the branch, this method works in windows; I cant confirm for other Linux/Mac.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP

Answer (score 5):

I personally confirmed that, on the new version, advanced branch management has been removed, and you can only delete branches from the website.

As a personal recommendation, you should give [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) a try. Works like a charm, it's free (requires a free registration), and even when it's originally developed to work with Atlassian's BitBucket repositories, it also works well with GitHub.

And BTW, with SourceTree, you can remove GitHub branches :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I delete a branch from the website... then, locally, it just says "publish" again, seems to be really no option to delete it, except from the command line. btw +1 for Source Tree, I have used it before, it is fantastic.

Comment: plus 1 for source tree.. that just solved my issue. it does let you do it - yep

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I have a strange behaviour with [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com): when I delete a branch in GitHub Shell, the branch continues to shown into the drop-down menù of GitHub Desktop! ... same behaviour with the "Delete branch-name..." function of GitHub Desktop.

I solved with `git show-ref`to list all refs

```
cf7c75b18e47a566f5bebccd3746f19fa426af4f refs/heads/master
cf7c75b18e47a566f5bebccd3746f19fa426af4f refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
540b3c8032f76ec13c84d6f40de885b996465dcb refs/remotes/origin/branch1
cf7c75b18e47a566f5bebccd3746f19fa426af4f refs/remotes/origin/branch2
```

when there are the ref to remote, GitHub Desktop can't delete at all the branch.

You can't remove a ref with `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/branch*` and then you have

```
cf7c75b18e47a566f5bebccd3746f19fa426af4f refs/heads/master
cf7c75b18e47a566f5bebccd3746f19fa426af4f refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Now you can remove the branc with `git branch -d branch*`

Answer (score 1):

**2021-July-28 Update**

I'm pleased to see now that in Github Desktop (at least on Mac) you can not only right+click a branch name and choose delete from the list of branches,

[image]

but, you can also choose to delete the branch on the remote as well in the confirmation dialogue. Naturally you'll want to confirm that's the action you wish before doing so.

[image]

**Original Command Line Instructions**

I know this is a question about the GUI, but [until the feature arrives](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5893), as a user of Github Desktop I find it easier to jump into the command line `ctl + ^` and use the following. If you have a lot to delete it is easier than switching to each branch...

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on branch which you want to delete it will show 3 options in that you have to click on delete.

[image]

Or if you want to delete current branch then select -> delete option from branch dropdown.

[image]

[image]